# How to skip adding daily conversion rate for select products?

Tags: magento-2.1, currency, multicurrency, currency-rates

So we have two websites each with their own store views in our store. Both websites share the same catalog. All products are imported and priced in US currency, and then our Canadian website applies the daily exchange rate to products.

The problem is that we have select products where a specific canadian selling price must be adhered too regardless of exchange rate/etc.

Is there a way to have the daily exchange rate NOT applied to a product if a specific attribute has a value?

Or does anybody know of an extension that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can not have different prices for different store views. The Price scope is global or website (System->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog Price Scope).

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, we have two separate websites, each with their own store_view, and one of those storeviews is US, and the other is Canadian. We apply different prices per product for each website.

Comment: Make sure when you go to System->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog Price Scope the scope is set to website. Then on your product page you should be able to set different prices for different websites.

Comment: Yes, thank you. However that really isn't the problem. Please re-read the question to better understand what I'm asking for.  
The root of the question: How to NOT apply the daily exchange rate to a product if that product has an attribute that has a value in it (we have an attribute called canadian_specific_price, if that has a value thats what we want to use, and NOT apply a daily exchange rate).